# Web User Control output caching when output caching is already enabled at the page level

Tags: asp.net, caching, user-controls, outputcache, web-user-controls

Easy question hopefully. . .  Is there any benefit to be gained by turning on output caching on Web User Controls if the pages they are displayed on already have output caching turned on?

My guess would be no, it is not worth it, but maybe I am missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turning on output caching on web user control will be useful only when the duration set for it is less than duration set for output cache of page. for more information you can refer to following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h30h475z(v=vs.71).aspx

hope this helps.